How to do a very large bulk update in MySQL?
I need to do a bulk update of a MySQL table.  I am updating one column, called Quantity, the same column in all cases.  The table primary key is an automatically-assigned numeric ID.  I can build a list in Excel of the affected IDs and the new Quantity value for each ID, like so:



ID
Quantity




1
25


2
15


3
22


4
1


5
128



I understand that I could do this using INSERT IGNORE and individual ID/Quantity value pairs, but in my case the complete list of changes will be over 3300 rows.  Is there a way that I can build this list of key/value pairs as a CSV, then have MySQL read the CSV and "for each row in CSV, find row with key X, and update field Quantity with value Y" - all in a single MySQL query?

IF you have the IDs and new values in a spreadsheet, you could create a SQL command for each row updated. e.g. UPDATE tablename SET Quantity=X WHERE ID=Y;

^ are you saying, if there is 10,000 they need to make 10,000 statements?

That's what I'd do. You could then export it as a text file and run the whole file at once < ing it into the mysql client. This is assuming it's a one off thing and not something they are needing to be automated.

You can use LOAD DATA with the REPLACE option to load the CSV file into the table.

LOAD DATA with REPLACE looks like the way I'll go.  Thanks for the help!
